# ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED with TaskManager and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, taskmanager

I want to automatize the data download directly from Chrome when my computer is in sleep-mode. I created an exe-file which execute my different python code (I use Selenium).

When I execute the .exe everything works when the computer is on. When it sleeps, I program the execution with TaskManager but a problem of connection to chrome appears :

```
ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
```

And I can not reach the website needed.Do you have some ideas?

Some clarification, I have already allowed my computer to stay connected even when the computer is in sleep mode. I followed these steps:

[https://thegeekpage.com/connected-to-internet-in-sleep-mode/#:~:text=Method%201%3A%20How%20to%20Keep,click%20on%20Power%20%26%20sleep%20option](https://thegeekpage.com/connected-to-internet-in-sleep-mode/#:%7E:text=Method%201%3A%20How%20to%20Keep,click%20on%20Power%20%26%20sleep%20option)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: While in sleep your computer stops network interface

Comment: Thank you @Aleksey for the answer.  Yes, I forgot to precise that I allowed the network interface to keep going when my computer is in sleep-mode. I followed the following steps : thegeekpage.com/connected-to-internet-in-sleep-mode/… Maybe it is not enough. Do you have any other recommendations ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go into your device manager
2. Locate your network card or wireless connection
3. Go to Advanced tab
4. Uncheck power saving mode.